# Angular2/Ionic 2 dynamic component property

Tags: angular, ionic2, ionice

I would like to ask for help on this issue. I was working on a dynamic component in angular 2 and ionic: Kindly check below scenario.

I have component name button-component:

```
<button-component [label]="I'm a button" **small**></button-component>
```

**small** - must be dynamically inputted in the button element like
**big** ,
**large**.

Inside button-component view file I have:

```
 <button "the single  attribute must appear here like small">{{label}}</button>
```

The output would be `<button small>I'm a button</button>`

I tried all the property bindings in angular 2 , but this is ionic property.

How can I do this with ionic 2 and angular 2. By using single attribute property dynamically.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Same as Angular 2, just send a `size` attribute and set it to `small`

```
<button-component label="'I'm a button'" size="'small'"></button-component>
```

Then in your button component:

```
@Input() size;
```

and in your template:

```
<button [class]="size">{{label}}</button>
```

And declare your desired styles in the CSS, for example:

```
.small {
...
}

.big {
..
}
```

Comment: Will try this one, Thank you

Comment: Error in ./ButtonComponent class ButtonComponent - caused by: Failed to execute 'setAttribute' on 'Element': '{{size}}' is not a valid attribute name.